# Pandas: concise way of finding and writing unique occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

For a dataframe such as this:

|  | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | D |
| 2 | B | A |
| 3 | C | B |

**Desired outcome:**

Unique occurrences of values in Col1 and Col2 in order of appearance by row

i.e. unique_list = [A, D, B, C]

**Problem**

Way to minimise iteration and processing due to number and size of dataframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first 2 columns, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and get unique values in [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
unique_list = df.iloc[:, :2].stack().unique().tolist()
print (unique_list)
['A', 'D', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Thank you for this: if there were more columns (lets say 10) and you still wanted to only use the first 2 then how would you specify this? And can you also specify the range of rows?